# Подсветка при нажатии на ImageView

Tags: java, android, xml, style

Доброго времени суток! Есть такая проблема. Я испльзую ImageView в качестве кнопки с изображением. Хочу чтобы при нажатии эта кнопка подсвечивалась. Делаю это вот так.
Сам ImageView

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/backButton" 
    style="@style/backButton"
    android:src="@drawable/back_button"
    android:layout_width="32dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:padding="32dp" />
```

Селектор для него

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <item>              
                <bitmap android:src="@drawable/ic_home_up" android:gravity="center" />
            </item>    
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">   
                    <size android:height="32dp" android:width="32dp"/>                         
                    <solid android:color="#55AACC33" />
                </shape>
            </item>         
        </layer-list>
    </item>

    <item android:state_pressed="false" >
        <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <item>              
                <bitmap android:src="@drawable/ic_home_up" android:gravity="center" />
            </item>                          
        </layer-list>
    </item>       
</selector>
```

Вроде бы все работает за исключением небольшой детали. Фон, который должен менять свой цвет при нажатии не растягивается на весь ImageView а представляет собой небольшой квадратик в центре ImageView. При этом независимо от того какой width и height я устанавливаю в теге size  размер фона не меняется.  Как сделать так чтобы этот фон пр нажатии был на весь размер ImageView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

используй атрибут `android:background` вместо `android:src`

Answer (score 0):

```
 android:layout_width="32dp"
 android:layout_height="32dp"
 android:padding="32dp" />
```

Здесь что-то не так. Весь ImageView занят областью *padding*, для изображения нет места. Т.е. *padding* нужно убрать. Затем, у ImageView нужно установить `android:scaleType="fitXY"`. Это единственный тип масштабирования, при котором применится `android:gravity="center"` у `bitmap` в селекторе (только в этом случае `ImageView` выполняет `Drawable.setBounds()`, передавая размеры всего канваса и масштабирование выполяет сам `drawable`).

Ну а проще всего поставить `drawable` с подсветкой на нажатия не в `src`, а отдельно в `background`:

```
<ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/ic_home_up"
            android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp" />
```

Со своим селектором, естественно.

Если нужно, чтобы подсветка рисовалась поверх изображения, а не под ним, то можно воспользоваться [ForegroundImageView](https://gist.github.com/JakeWharton/0a251d67649305d84e8a) и ставить не `bacgrkound`, а `foreground`